# JSON Ajax PHP MYSQL - multiple records into JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a call to this php script (only part in question displayed)

```
if (mysql_num_rows($pquery) == 1) {
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($pquery);

   $query_ht = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE pid='$result[id]'");
   $ht_result = mysql_fetch_array($query_ht); // THIS WILL ALWAYS RETURN 3 ROWS

   //echo json_encode($result); //THis will always contain one row
   //echo json_encode($ht_result); // THIS WILL ALWAYS contain 3 ROWS
```

UPDATE:

```
   //echo json_encode(array(
       //'comp' => $result,
       //'ht' => $ht_result)
       // );
```

### This works, but I dont think it is pretty..... Any suggestions

```
  $query_htl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE pid='$result[id]' AND type='L'");
   $query_htg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE pid='$result[id]' AND type='G'");
   $query_htr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE pid='$result[id]' AND type='R'");
   $ht_resultl = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_htl);
   $ht_resultg = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_htg);
   $ht_resultr = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_htr);
   echo json_encode(array(
       'comp' => $result,
       'htL' => $ht_resultl,
       'htG' => $ht_resultg,
       'htR' => $ht_resultr)
        );

}
```

When I am echoing one or the other I am ok.. But i do not know how to return everything to jquery

jquery script:

```
$('#c_search').submit(function(){
       data = ($(this).serialize());

  $.ajax({
      url: 'actions/get_company.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(selected){
```

i can call with:

```
alert(selected.htL.id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine all results in common array:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
die(json_encode(array(
    'result'    => $result,
    'ht_result' => $ht_result
)));
```

Comment: Thanks dfsq for the help. IT has me just about their. I updated the php line above. i get 1 of the rows packed into the array.. should i be using a for each loop to insert all three rows into the array?

Comment: First of all, you don't need three queries. In your case use `SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE pid='$result[id]' AND type IN ('L', 'G', 'R')`